# Missing links/words for sharing options

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

`Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, , , or .`

That is what it says under posts. Is this a bug or something, and if so, can it please be fixed?

Comment: Since this appears to be an ad blocker issue (per your comment below), I'm marking this as [tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work ok for me

[image]

Can you add a screenshot, browser used, macOS/iOS version etc? Also, do you have any AdBlockers or similar activated?

Answer (score 3):

Those are social links, which means they’ll be blocked if you have a content blocker or extension blocking links to those places. For example, [Fanboy’s Social Blocking List](https://easylist.to/easylist/fanboy-social.txt) from [EasyList](https://easylist.to) contains the following, which will remove the sharing links for Google+, Facebook and Twitter. EasyList is built into AdBlock, uBlock Origin and more, with this particular list optional and usually off by default.

```
##[href^="//plus.google.com/share"]
##a[href*="facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?"]
##a[href="https://twitter.com/share"]
```

Comment: Oh I suppose that that's AdBlock Plus doing that, I'll turn it off